# Grafana not supporting Alert other than TimeSeries Visualization

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

I want to achieve an alert for my variable count of services(ex:227) of gauge-based visualization. But in the panel of the Dashboard of Grafana, I cannot see the Alert tab, but when I select Timeseries as Visualization, I can see the Alert tab. However, my data doesn't have a timestamp and it sends data for a count of services only.
Please refer to below link for images.

[Gauge as a visualtization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDLNX.png)
[Timeseries as a visualtization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmWQb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Alerting on Gauge is not supported. You can follow the github issue [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6983)

in the mean time you can hack your SQL to be a timeseries and only care about the last instance:

```
select now() as time, count(*) As single_stat from my_table
union all
select now()-interval '10 minute', '0'
union all
select now()-interval '20 minute', '0'
union all
select now()-interval '30 minute', '0'
```